# How to plot time series clusters in R?

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, cluster-analysis

Just read the ["Mining time series data" pdf](http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~jessica/BookChapterTSMining.pdf) by Ratanamahatana, Lin, Gunopulos and Keogh. Did someone know how to visualize time series clusters in R like in the Figure 1.7?
[image]

Comment: Is your question how to plot the 'warping matrix', or how to plot two time series aligned by warping (as in Fig. 1.3)? Figure 1.4 illustrates the use of dynamic programming and a warping matrix using two example sequences. It seems unlikely that this is what you actually want. Could you be a bit more precise? Have you computed pairwise distances between a set of time series using this warping technique, or are you aiming to do so?

Comment: @micans It should be Figure 1.7. Sorry. Let me correct the question.

Comment: My goal is to find and visualize a similarities in about a hundred of different time series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can visualize 100s of Time Series sequences with Sparklines. If you also want to the Hierarchical ordering, the you could attain that in 2 steps.

1. Sort your data.frame of Times Series sequences by their multi-level clusters. (This assumes that you have computed the cluster hierarchy for each series.)
2. Download and install the [SparkTable](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sparkTable/index.html) in your R setup. Now plot the Sparklines for your TS sequences. Take a look at this Inside-R page for [SparkEPS](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sparkTable/docs/sparkEPS).

[This answer on statExchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8242/plotting-sparklines-in-r) is exactly what you need for the plotting part, so I am not reproducing the same example here.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This figure *most likely* is made with a *drawing* program, not with a data mining software.

Nobody would run cluster analysis on 6 observations like this. It's easier to look at them visually and do it manually than figuring out how to have a program visualize it this way.